# How to disable JavaScript in Cocoa WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I'd like to use Cocoa WebView for display of email messages. For security/privacy purposes I want to disable JavaScript but, incredibly enough, can't find any way to do it in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000164i).

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `WebView`'s [-(WebPreferences *)preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903-BABGICHG), which has a [-(void)setJavascriptEnabled:(BOOL)flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebPreferences_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001900-BCICEJEF) option.